# Windows clean installation on Tablet

Tags: windows-10, tablet

I am guessing why during installation of windows 10 on my tablet the touchscreen work, and when i complete installation it stop works.
Is there a way to take the drivers from installation?

Comment: Hello, welcome. It's not so clear what you are asking. Your touchscreen doesn't work after installing Windows? Have you tried downloading drivers from the tablet manufacturer's website?

Comment: The touchscreen work during the first setup of windows 10 when you choose drive where install etc.. but when finish installation it stop work.Manufactirer not provide drivers...

Comment: What is the tablet make and model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you re installing Windows 10 and booting form installation media you are loaded into Windows PE (Preinstallation Environment). It includes typically the generic driver for storage, video, input (including touch screen).

When Windows is installed it uses [another type of drivers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/where-setup-searches-for-drivers) that exist in its Windows' [driver store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/driver-store).
Some of these drivers come with the Windows image, but most of them must be installed manually after installation.

So, you just need to install touch screen drivers after Windows installation manually to make it work properly.

Comment: okey in device management i don't see elements with warning in yellow triangle.What's the name i could search?

Comment: In Dev. manager it should be in Human Interface Devices. In my case it's "Wacom device" there in the list.